# disable DispForm.aspx?

Tags: permissions, office-365, access, sharepoint-library

I'm trying to stop authorized users that have access to SharePoint lists to view records directly in SharePoint.

Currently I allow users to view / edit data via linked SharePoint lists with MS Access. but I don't want them to be able to view them in SharePoint.

I've disabled all search facilities in SharePoint so its hidden from them but if they go to the record directly they can view it.

> https://mtengland-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mt@mtnhs.uk/Lists/MainData/DispForm.aspx?ID=17299

Using Office 365

is there any work around?

Comment: Are you able to use a different database? Stripping a SharePoint List down and treating it as a SQL table is likely more work than it's worth.

Comment: unfortunatly no :( and its driving me mad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a redirect script (what ever your code of choice is) on load to redirect them to a different page by adding a script editor part to the page. I know it's not an an iron clad solution but just another deterrent.

Comment: That's exactly what i just did! worked a treat I also adjusted the display forms to not show any fields just in case and along with CSS modifcations

Comment: Hi! i have the same problem, i just do not know how o add a redirect script. How can i edit and add a javascript redirect on the Dispform.apx file ?